# Issue with JSON conversion to POJO mapping

Tags: java, json, rest

I am mapping some JSON values into my POJO.
The problem is that there are more applications who consume same Webservices, so the number of fields provided in JSON is not specific.

> JSON file:  Like {"A":A,"B":B}

But my POJO contains 3 fields

```
class A{
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
}
```

How will I handle the value which is not provided to me or it will directly map null?

Comment: Use jackson's `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`

Comment: Jsonignore property generally works when we have more elements in JSON as compared to POJO. Will it also work in reverse way when I have less fields in JSON as compared to POJO ?

Comment: It will be mapped as null. You don't have to change your code.

Comment: So I guess you mean no need to change the code declare the simple variable" String a; "and it will automatically do no need to annotate anything or "@JsonIgnoreProperties(IgnoreUnknown=true)"